# Retrieving sql data in iframes

Tags: sql, iframe

I have a php script (ini.php), that open in an iframe inside of "main.php":
 `<iframe src='ini.php' style='width:650px;' frameborder='0' id="IDMain" allowtransparency="YES" scrolling="NO"></iframe>`
The SQL does not retrieve the data in "ini.php".
But if I incorporate the code of "ini.php" in "main.php", without using an iframe, the query retrieves all the information.
I must have an iframe in order to change all the different scripts in the same iframe.
Any help here?
Thanks

In addition more information:

The main.php is in session after logged. Previously I had the whole frame repeated in each script, and everything was ok.main.php, ini.php, and so on. Each script with header, left, right, main and footer. To make it faster and easier I decide to make the main script called main.php, that with an included script called config.inc.php that has several functions, also  connects to data base, to retrieve some data to the header,  left , right and footer sides of the main area (iframe) where the others different scripts, just to  opens inside of a iframe, maintaining the information around. Each script, (like ini.php), that runs in the iframe also include the config.inc.php file, to connect as well to database. But does not retrieve any information
The connection to database in config script is:

`<$connect=mysql_connect ("localhost","database","password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database", $connect) or die ("'I cannot connect to the database ");  >`

The query in ini,php (and others) is:

`

```
 if ($id) { 
$id_session=$_SESSION['id_session'];
$namesession=$_SESSION['name_session'];
$sql="select * from data where id='$id_sessino' limit 1 ";
$result=mysql_db_query("database",$sql);
$regist=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$id=$regist["id"];
$id_session=$regist["id"];
$namesession=$regist["name_session"]; 
$country=$regist["country"];
And soo on…
}
```

`

I hope with is information it makes it clear what do I mean. Thank you

Comment: A bit more information (e.g. the source or any error logs produced by the scripts). Could it be you are opening the database connection in `main.php` and then try to use it in `ini.php`? As the iframed script runs separately from the one in the parent page it wouldn't have any connection to the database (and hence couldn't retrieve any data).

Comment: thank you for your questions. I edit the original question. Can you read it to find if now is more clear my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check PHP help for [mysql_db_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php). Since you are not giving it any open db link, it tries to do some default magic, which likely fails, because, as I mentioned in the comment, the two scripts (in parent window and inside the iframe) are run separately and have no idea about each other *unless you are doing some synchronizing, that isn't shown in the code snippets. That means that the iframe script doesn't know anything about the connection you've opened in the parent page, and fails. Check your logs, you should see some `E_WARNING` complaints (if you are logging this level).

Also, as the documentation says, you might be better off with `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extensions. But the principle will remain the same - the script in questoin has to have an open connection to the database (and I'm not sure whether you can *easily and safely* transfer an open from one script to the other one, so you'll likely have to do it all in the iframe script).

Answer (score 0):

Try two things, first I would change the MySQL_fetch_array part to

```
While($regist = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//Code goes here
}
```

Secondly try referring to the array vales as numbers rather than names, so regist['id'] would become regist[0]. They will be in the order the are in the database.

Also since you select your database when creating connection why not just use mysql_query("QUERY HERE"); Rather than mysql_db_query